# Segmented control or another iOS control?

Tags: ios, iphone, user-interface

in ios 8 how can i implement the controls that permit to switch to different sections like the Spring app?

[image]

It's a custom segmented control?

Comment: No, I think that's a horizontally scrolling scroll view with individual buttons.

Comment: You could use a `UICollectionView` with `UIButtons`.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it is a custom control.

You can create it with a scrollView:

1) calculate the frame of the contentSize of the scrollView and set it.

2) add the buttons/labels to the scrollView with your margins between them.

3) add functionality to handle selection (springiness/magnetism..etc').